# Regex, extract variable name

Tags: c#, regex

I am in a situation that I need to extract words/variables from a string(expression). I tried to accomplish this. The following situation is valid:

```
OK/Test(ANSWER[12])+SUM(Test(ANSWER[..]))*OK+ANSWER[14]
```

I need to extract the "OK" "variables". I managed to extract other components like ANSWER[..] e.g. These variables are dynamic ofcourse.

I already tried things like:

```
/[a-zA-Z]*(?!\(|\[)/g
```

But this also returns SU (From SUM, which is not desired)

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: clarification

I need to extract words that are only surrounded by whitespace (begin or end of string) or +-*/ operators. Words that have ()[] before or after them should be ignored.

Comment: I tried to explain myself better in a edit I did just make. I just use Regex.Matches(). So any C# code is irrelevant right?

Comment: The code is also relevant as you posted a regex literal and C# does not support this notation. Try `@"(?<![^\s+*/-])\w+(?![^\s+*/-])"` or `@"(?<![^\s+*/-])[A-Za-z]+(?![^\s+*/-])"` (depending on what the "word" is for you here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<![^\s+*/-])\w+(?![^\s+*/-])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5B%5E%5Cs%2B*%2F-%5D%29%5Cw%2B%28%3F!%5B%5E%5Cs%2B*%2F-%5D%29&i=OK%2FTest%28ANSWER%5B12%5D%29%2BSUM%28Test%28ANSWER%5B..%5D%29%29*OK%2BANSWER%5B14%5D%20)

**Details**

- `(?<![^\s+*/-])` - a whitespace boundary with `+`, `-`, `/` and `*`  included
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `(?![^\s+*/-])`  - a whitespace boundary with `+`, `-`, `/` and `*`  included

C# sample code:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<![^\s+*/-])\w+(?![^\s+*/-])")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Value);
```